# Перетащить элементы из одного списка в другой через цикл

Tags: python-3.x, list

Есть функция которая находит самое короткое слово в списке. Нужно с помощью этой функции остортировать список, чтобы самые короткие слова были в начале и самые длинные в конце. Я пытаюсь через for, но максимум, что я получаю тоже самое короткое слово, что и в первой функции. И честно говоря не понимаю, как связать `i` c `get_min_len_word`. 
Думала также сделать пустой список `а=[]` и попробовать через `а.append`, но такой код не работает.

```
def get_min_len_word(string_list): 
    return min(string_list, key=len)

for i in string_list:
    return string_list.pop(string_list.index(get_min_len_word(string_list)))
```

Comment: Приведите код полностью. Тот, который не работает.

Comment: А вам обязательно именно через эту функцию нужно отсортировать? В питоне есть гораздо более правильные и эффективные способы отсортировать слова по длине?

Answer (score 4):

Если это обязательное условие - использовать функцию get_min_len_world, то можно сделать так:

```
res = []
while string_list:
  res.append(
    string_list.pop(
      string_list.index(
        get_min_len_word(string_list))))

print(res)
```

Но это очень неэффективный способ. Гораздо правильнее сортировать без всяких посторонних функций:

```
res = sorted(string_list, key=len)
```

Comment: Да, это обязательное условие. Видимо препод хочет чтобы мы смогли научится использовать функцию в фунции.
Ваш код у меня не хочет работать. Выдает None столько раз, сколько элементов в списке, если использовать принт, и один ноне если ретурн.
Не знаю, как правильно код добавить первой функции




def get_min_len_word(string_list):
       
    return min(string_list, key=len)

Comment: После выполнения моего кода результат будет лежать в переменной res. Просто допишите после цикла print(res) и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Вы простите, я еще совсем глупая. У меня не выходит. Если я пишу ретурн рес, тогда я получаю самое короткое слово и больше ничего, если я пишу принт рес, то он мне выдает не один сортированный список, а 4 списка. Если изначальный список был ['jok', 'bebe', 'c', 'ac'], то я получаю:
['c']
['c', 'ac']
['c', 'ac', 'jok']
['c', 'ac', 'jok', 'bebe']

Comment: Покажите полностью весь ваш код.

Comment: @Teepot, дело в том, что в python (в отличие от большинства других языков) отступы имеют значение. Вы, судя по всему, перед принтом ставите отступ и в итоге принт оказывается внутри цикла, и поэтому срабатывает при каждом проходе цикла. А нужно писать принт с таким же отступом, как и слово while - тогда принт выполнится только после того, как цикл полностью завершится. Я поправил мой ответ, теперь вы можете в нём увидеть, как правильно расположить принт.

Comment: Да, все так как вы говорите, спасибо большое!

Comment: @Teepot, пожалуйста, обращайтесь ещё :) А если вы симпатичная, то можете прямо мне писать xD

Comment: я бы с удовольствием, только я так понимаю тут это невозможно :)